# undefined error with ajaxcall to receive json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

my problem is that I
can not solve this problem

If I call the php script, all I get is an undefined error

this is the code I use for testing AND

[this is the original code from the creator that is giving me a headache](http://anantgarg.com/2009/05/13/gmail-facebook-style-jquery-chat/)

```
function startJsonSession(){     
    $.ajax({        url: "jsontest.php?action=startjson",       
        cache: false,     
        dataType: "json",   
         complete: function(data) {             
             username = data.username;               
              alert(username);      
         }    
    });
}

//phpscript

if ($_GET['action'] == "startjson") { startJson(); } 


    function startJson() {   

header('Content-type: application/json'); 
    $items = '';     
echo json_encode(array(          
     "username" => "bob",    
    "items" => array( "item1" => "sandwich",   
    "item2" => "applejuice"  
    )     
    )); 


 }
```

thanks, Richard

edited my question because:
this function returns the json data in a different way
and therefore the solution presented below, does not have the same outcome.

```
function startChatSession() {
    $items = '';
    if (!empty($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'])) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['openChatBoxes'] as $chatbox => $void) {
            $items .= chatBoxSession($chatbox);
        }
    }


    if ($items != '') {
        $items = substr($items, 0, -1);
    }

header('Content-type: application/json');
?>
{
        "username": "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>",
        "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
}

<?php


    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: are you getting an error message at all?

Comment: are you calling the function named by 'action' (in the $_POST) dynamically because action==startjson and function==startjsonSession().  Just trying to rule it out...

Comment: I should have clarified, your querystring is url: "jsontest.php?action=startjson" and the php function is startjsonSession, so if your php handling looks like return $_POST['action']() kinda thing then it won't call the function

Comment: edited my question, but you where faster

Comment: could be mistaken, but i think $.ajax is a $_POST, so try looking if $_POST['action'] === "startjson"

Comment: I don't get an error message because i don't test for it, but if I use the success function I would get no success. I assume it is a parseerror then.

Comment: You sure,because I thought everything you stick behind an url can be retrieved by get. Anyway the original code is not from me, but I will test for that also. Be back in a bit!.

Answer (score 2):

I recreated with your code and figured it out.  The object being returned is of type XMLHttpRequest.  Its got a property called responseText holding a json string with the data.

so this works..

```
var decodedData = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")");
username = decodedData.username;
alert(username);
```

A bit messy but it does the trick :-)

p.s If it helps, I figured it out using firebug in firefox and sticking a breakpoint in the js code

Edited below:
Without wanting to do the eval, you could use this and it works:

```
$.getJSON("json.php?action=startjson",

  function(data) {
    username = data.username;
    alert(username);
  }
);
```

Edited to show what I did with the success function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "json.php?action=startjson",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {

    username = data.username;
    alert(username);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that like a bad workaround. I read eval is not always relyable with json. I will try your solution to see if I can get the whole chatcode to work. If you are interested. I put the link to the original code from the creator in my question. I hope I don't have to change a lot in the original code.

Comment: eval() is not safe, i.e if you don't trust the source. if you look at json.org  then you can find some parsers, like http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval/

Comment: I looked at the original and the difference is instead of specifying a "complete" function, it specifies a "success".  That seems to do any eval'ing or whatever beforehand, then the "data" is already a js object

Comment: Ok, but that one returns undefined also

Comment: hmm, then I'm stuck. I just tried that and it worked fine on mine with only that change to your original post :-(

Comment: Did you used eval with the original function and it worked or without eval, but with the success function??

Comment: I commented on your other similar post.  Essentially your php response is empty for some reason :-(

Comment: Yes, and I really want to find out why

Comment: you could modify the php code as an experiment to call the function regardless and see what happens...

Comment: @Dave jquery uses eval() internally when the dataType is set to json

Comment: that's all the function does anyway
It executes right after document ready.
All it has to do, is give back the session variable
So, it must be in the syntax

Comment: @redsquare thanks for the info, I wasn't sure how it did it exactly

Comment: One other thing I can think off is that my hoster is not supporting something. I am just saying something because other people have got it working with no problems at all. Maybe it's the heredoc in the php??

Comment: might have broken on the call to json_encode if its php version < 5.2 (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Is username a global variable?
If not you should prepend the "var" keyword.

username = data.username -> var username = data.username;

Comment: username is only used inside the completion function, so this shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: This could lead to "undefined" errors in IE and break the current page.

Answer (score 0):

also what I don't understand is that it breaks out off php mode, instead of echoing it back like it's done with xml

```
?>
{
        "username": "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>",
        "items": [
            <?php echo $items;?>
        ]
}

<?php
```

is this the same as above (object array containing literal array)?

```
echo json_encode(array(          
             "username" => "bob",    
             "items" => $items
        )     
             ));  
 }
```

Comment: i think thats just the same as e.g spitting out literal chars same as with html.  Just a different style of doing the same thing

Comment: yes thats manually doing what the json_encode function does.  Obviously safer to use json_encode since handwriting can caws errurs :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I got it working.

I installed firebug and saw that the php script was returning html headers instead off json.

All off the sudden it started working, I really would like to know what the problem was, but I can't tell you.

Anyway, thanks for sticking so long, David